# Upload files to Sharepoint site in specific subfolder

Tags: powershell

I have a very simple script where I upload files to a folder in a SharePoint site. But I would like to upload them to a "subfolder".
Can anyone help me modify my script?

It looks like this at the moment:

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "mysite"
$spList = $spWeb.Lists["Reports"]
$file = [io.file]::ReadAllBytes('D:\temp\test.rdl')
$spList.RootFolder.Files.Add("test.rdl",$file)
```

So under folder "Reports" I have plenty of Subfolders where I would like to upload my files insted of root folder "Reports".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
$folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)
$folder.Files.Add("test.rdl", $file)
```